# Batch file to count file types in sub directories

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a batch file that counts certain file types in sub directories. In this case it's .txt and .xls files. At the end of the file it reports this back.

```
@echo off
REM get script directory
set scriptdir=%~dp0
REM change directory to script directory
cd /d %scriptdir%
setlocal
set txtcount=0
set xlscount=0
for %%x in ('dir *.txt /s ) do set /a txtcount+=1
for %%x in ('dir *.xls /s ) do set /a xlscount+=1
echo %txtcount% text files
echo %xlscount% .xls files
endlocal
pause
```

My batch file doesn't report back the correct count of files. I thought it might be continually counting but I've set the count variables to local so I'm not sure what's up.

Comment: You should always include concrete examples of what a script/program is doing (not just "the wrong count") and what you expect/want it to be.  In this case, the inside of your `for` loop isn't doing what you think it is: it's running for `'dir`, every text file in the current directory and `/s`. You might find `for /r %%x in (*.txt) do...` works better

Comment: Sometimes reading the help for the command you are trying to use, will help you solve your problem yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's three problems with your script:

- You want to iterate over command output, so you need `FOR /F`
- You're not using the "bare" `/B` format, i.e. `DIR` outputs more than just filenames
- You're missing the closing single quote twice

Replace your loops with this:

```
FOR /F %%X IN ('DIR /S /B *.txt') DO SET /A "txtcount+=1"
FOR /F %%X IN ('DIR /S /B *.xls') DO SET /A "xlscount+=1"
```

Answer (score 4):

You are very close, but you are missing the switch `/B` of the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), so the output contains a header and a footer, which are both included in the count. Therefore, change `dir *.txt /s` to `dir *.txt /s /b` (same for `*.xls`) and the count is going to be correct.

Besides that, there are typos: the closing `'` is missing -- `for %%x in ('dir *.txt /s') do ...`. In addition, the `/F` switch at [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is missing, which is needed to capture the output of a command. (I assume these things are present in the true script as you would receive errors otherwise.)

---

#### Alternative Approach

To count the number of files, you could also do the following:

```
for /F "delims=" %%X in ('dir /B /S "*.txt" ^| find /C /V ""') do set "COUNT=%%X"
```

[`find /V ""`](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) searches for non-empty lines, hence all lines returned by `dir /B /S` are considered as matches; the `/C` switch simply lets `find` return the total amount of matching lines.